# ListSelectionEvent fire 2 triggers asynchronously when clicking rows/columns

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jtable, listselectionlistener

ListSelectionEvent fire 2 triggers asynchronously when clicking rows/columns

Should i change any thing with my code??

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class JTableListSelectionListener {

public static void main(String[] a) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

final JTable table;

String[] columnTitles = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
Object[][] rowData = { { "11", "12", "13", "14" }, { "21", "22", "23", "24" },
    { "31", "32", "33", "34" }, { "41", "42", "44", "44" } };

table = new JTable(rowData, columnTitles);

table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
ListSelectionModel cellSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
cellSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    String selectedData = null;

    int[] selectedRow = table.getSelectedRows();
    int[] selectedColumns = table.getSelectedColumns();

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < selectedColumns.length; j++) {
        selectedData = (String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow[i], selectedColumns[j]);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Selected: " + selectedData);
  }

});

frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));

frame.setSize(300, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Output will be

Selected: 42

Selected: 42

Selected: 33

Selected: 33

But i want to trigger single event whenever user clicks particular row or column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ListSelectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting--) to check it isn't (changing).

> Returns whether or not this is one in **a series of multiple events,** where changes are still being made. See the documentation for `ListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(boolean)` for more details on how this is used.

Answer (score 2):

Added getValueIsAdjusting() as suggested by Andrew Thompson and updated code will be

```
cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

    if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        return;
    }
    ..
```